# JLPT N3 Practice Vocabulary 2 すこしでは ありませんが

Tags: jlpt

From #8 of 日本語能力試験３級の模擬試験　-語彙２- (http://jlpt.u-biq.org/3v2.html)

> **８）しばらく おまちください。**

Choose the one with the closest meaning.

> A) ぜんぜん またなくても いいです。
>   
>  B) すこし まってください。
>   
>  **C) すこしでは ありませんが まってください。**
>   
>  D) とても ながい じかん まってください。

I can see none of the others mean "Please wait for a while", but why is it C? I mainly don't understand the すこしでは ありませんが part.

Comment: ?? I think the answer is B..... ええっ「すこしまってください」を選んだら、× になった。。

Comment: 「９）あの ひとは あたまが おかしいです。」すごく「あの ひとは あたまが おもしろいです。」にしたい衝動に駆られるw

Comment: およ。１０番の４つ目の選択肢「あ**ぞ**びに行きます」になっとるがな・・

Comment: The question of the exam is bad. From the meaning of the word, I can understand that the answer is C. But C is an inappropriate Japanese. If someone said like C  in business, the client might be angry.

Comment: I contacted the site owner. They corrected the errors. Now their page shows すこしまってください as the correct answer. They also corrected the typo あ**ぞ**びにいきます to あ**そ**びにいきます in Question #10.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer should be B) すこしまってください。

「しばらくお[待]{ま}ちください」 is the polite way of saying 
「[少]{すこ}し待ってください」.

問題を載せているサイトの回答が間違ってると思います。

---

UPDATE:

I contacted the site owner, and they fixed the error. Now their page marks 「すこしまってください」 as the correct answer.

[image]

Comment: Hi Chocolate, `しばらくおまちください` and `少々おまちください` have different meanings right? (待つ時間の長さが違う）. `C`は自然な日本語じゃないけど、意味的にあっているので、Cが正解だと思います。

Comment: `しばらくおまちください and 少々おまちください have different meanings` -> 明鏡国語辞典で「しばらく」を引くと、「しばらく（＝少々）お待ちください」って載ってます。`Cが正解だと思います`- > 「少し待ってください」をお客さんに丁寧に言いたいとき、Jesseさんはなんて言うんですか。角川国語辞典で「しばらく」を引くと「少しの間」って載ってます。

Comment: その辞書は持ってないですが、しばらく=少々はあやまりだと思います。[この回答](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1059545.html)にも書いてあるんですが、待つ時間が違うので、私は「しばらく」と「少々」を使い分けてます。

Comment: Chocolateの言うとおり、「すこしでは ありませんが まってください」を言う人はいませんね・・・ただ、「自然な表現を選んでください」って書いてないです。「closest meaning」ってあるから、意味的に似ているものを選べばいいです。

Comment: （「しばらく」のほうが「すこし」より長いという前提のもとで）「少しではありませんが」に別に違和感がなかったのですが，私だけでしょうか？　確かにビジネスライクな言い方ではないですが，フレンドリーな会話なら普通に起こると思います．　我々が「少し」で想像する時間よりも長く待たせることに対する申し訳無さを込めた表現です．

Comment: I can understand that C is said as a joke when the speaker keeps you waiting for a bit long but it is unnatural in the general public. And しばらくお待ちください can mean 少し待ってください.

Comment: @chocolate OMG I have to at least admit that the question was not so good...

Comment: I've removed my downvote and now upvoted the answer. Thanks chocolate.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase すこしでは ありませんが まってください is highly contrastive to すこし まってください.

As you may know, すこし まってください means something like "wait a minute." Here, the word すこし indicates how long you have to wait.

In C, すこし is replaced with すこしでは ありませんが, that means "though it is not *a minute*". It is describing the speaker's feeling that "I can't say すこし as it is too long..."

Now, the word しばらく is "for a while", which is (at least I think) longer than すこし, so the answer is C.

Though D is also longer than すこし, there's no nuance of とても ながい in the word しばらく.